# "multiple definition of `atexit'" when linking with DLL

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, g++, mingw

I use MinGW32 more specifically TDM-GCC-32. I have very simple project I link to one custom library but this error pops out:

```
>g++ -D_WIN32 -D_MINGW -lgdi32 -lgdiplus -Linterception/x86 -linterception main.cpp -o interceptor.exe

interception/x86/libinterception.a(dgnes00125.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definitio
n of `atexit'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2c0):
 first defined here
interception/x86/libinterception.a(dgnes00109.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definitio
n of `_onexit'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2d0):
 first defined here
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/TD
M-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in
 section `.eh_frame'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Commands I use to build the library:

```
gcc -DINTERCEPTION_EXPORT -D_WIN32 -D_MINGW -shared -o interception.dll interception.c
dlltool -z interception.def --export-all-symbol interception.dll
dlltool -d interception.def -l libinterception.a
```

I guess I have to use different options for compiling the library to avoid redefinitions..

Comment: I tried them and it doesn't solve my issue...

Comment: You should improve your question showing the alternatives you have tried.

Comment: Try without `-D_WIN32 -D_MINGW`, I'd expect any such macros to be built into the compiler build

Comment: Try having `main.cpp` before the `-l` flags. Also check that "gcc" and "g++" both refer to the same installation, and your paths are correct

Comment: No changes. By the way the library I'm trying to use with MinGW https://github.com/oblitum/Interception It worked perfectly fine when I used it with MSVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dlltool` method I believe is currently deprecated. I can't fault you here though, as most of the available documentation still says to do it this way.

Gcc will link directly against `.dll` files, making `.a` files obsolete (at least for dealing with dll's - the only current reason to use a `.a` file is for static linking).  You don't even have to specify the dll with the `-l` flag, although you have to specify the path of the dll if it's not in your current directory

```
C:\Users\burito>gcc main.o opengl32.dll -o main.exe
gcc: error: opengl32.dll: No such file or directory

C:\Users\burito>gcc main.o c:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll -o main.exe

C:\Users\burito>
```

Ok, `opengl32.dll` is perhaps not a great example, but I hope I've given you the general idea.

I *believe* MSVC still needs its `.lib` files to use a `.dll`, for which there are several ways of making them if the library doesn't come with one.

In your specific case, the command that should work would be...

```
g++ -D_WIN32 -D_MINGW -lgdi32 -lgdiplus interception/x86/interception.dll main.cpp -o interceptor.exe
```

If for whatever reason you really do need to create a `.a` file from a `.dll`, the command that has worked for me is...

```
gendef interception.dll
dlltool -l interception.a -d interception.def -k -A
```

As the repository you linked does provide `.dll` files in its releases, you shouldn't have to build them yourself

Comment: I remember I solved this myself yeah something was wrong with the command IIRC. Thanks anyway! :)